# Efficient way to compare objects manually?

Tags: algorithm

**Scenario**: 
I have a list of 'items' in sql db and I want it to be consistent with third party source (list of 'items').

**Problem**:
To update local 'items' i am running 2 loops (with inner loops) - first to find new items, update already inserted item and second to find local items to delete.

**What i want**: Is there more efficient/tricky way to compare two lists to find new/redundant items from third party service?

Comment: Hm. Can you post some code? Would certainly help to understand the problem better.

Comment: you should consider adding the tag of your database (because if feels the solution is not to fetch all the items of the third party source... and yours as well). From an algorithmic standpoint though, you may compare two arrays in O(n) if they are both sorted